# Is it possible to build a small user login website with wordpress?

Tags: web, wordpress

I am planning to build a small website that lets users create an account and upload some stuff (a few photos). It is just a project and I was wondering whether it could be done using wordpress.

Are wordpress and its plugins powerful enough? Or would you recommend another approach to build this kind of website?

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You will find many examples and plugins to assist you in doing this. It's quite a broad topic to discuss.

Comment: @BigBadOwl Great! Do you know any examples? And also, were can I learn more about this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [WP Buddypress Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress/)

> BuddyPress is Social Networking, the WordPress way. Easily create a
>   fully featured social network inside your WordPress.org powered site.

Comment: Just one word of warning with BuddyPress. Depending on your knowledge, you may find BuddyPress a bit of a pain in the ass. If you already know a lot about WordPress, you'll have to rethink things to suit BuddyPress. I hand-rolled [Jottify](http://jottify.com) using just WordPress via the development of a very advanced theme.

Comment: Yeah i agree. You need some experience while working with Budypress.

Answer (score 1):

yes you van use the different CMS like the **JOOMLA, Drupal** for social networking site or you also search the plugins for you site in word press and joomla.

Comment: you can usae this  plugin YD BuddyPress Feed Syndication: http://wordpress.org/plugins/yd-buddypress-feed-syndication/